# Numpy genfromtxt removes underscore

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to load a file with numpy's genfromtxt method, using the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
input = np.genfromtxt(open('test.csv', 'rb'), dtype=None, delimiter=',', names=True)
```

The test.csv file looks like this:

```
col1,col2
one,1_1
two,2_2
three,3_3
```

This works fine in Python 2. However in Python 3 the underscores get removed and the result is `array([(b'one', 11), (b'two', 22), (b'three', 33)], dtype=[('col1', 'S5'), ('col2', '<i8')])`

I've already looked at the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), but I can't find any explanation for it.

Comment: I may be missing something, but in Python 3, literals like `1_234_567_890` are exactly the same as `1234567890`, `12_34_5_6_789_0` and the like.

Comment: Oh you're right, I didn't know that. Changing dtype to be both 'S5', does not remove the underscore. Thank you!